# VBA VLookup Dynamic Range

Tags: vba, excel

First off:
On sheet1 I have a set of data on column A and a datatype on column F.
On sheet2 I have a huge list with the same data on column A and the same datatype on column B as on F above. Each data point in column A is set with a data type on column B

Now my question:
The code I wrote compares the data in sheet2(A2:A2978) with the data in sheet1(A3:A271).
If they ARE NOT the same then it gives me a MsgBox with an Error and goes to the next data point.
If they ARE the same it goes and checks if sheet2(B2:B2978) is the same as sheet1(F3:F271).
If they ARE NOT the same again an error and it continues.
If they ARE the same it just goes to the next data point in the A column.

This code works for now. The problem is that I want to make the sheet1 and 2 to a dynamic range since I want to later change the code so I can use it on differen excel files with different amount of rows and the main file where I take the data from can also change.
I tried to do it with:

```
Set refRng = Tabelle2.Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
```

instead of

```
Set refRng = Tabelle2.Range("A2:A2978")
```

But as soon as I do that the code doesn't go to the next cycle anymore it just stays in the compare A column.
The VLookup looks as follows:

```
strTextSearch = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c.Value, refRng, 1, False)
```

And this is the whole code which works completly fine except for dynamic range:

```
Sub CompareData()    
    Dim strTextSearch        As String
    Dim strTextMain          As String
    Dim strText              As String
    Dim count                As Long
    Dim refRng               As Range
    Dim tarRng               As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    '// Change range to data you want to target
    Set tarRng = Tabelle1.Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(271, 2))

    For Each c In tarRng       
        With c
            count = count + 1

            Set refRng = Tabelle2.Range("A2:A2978")

            'c.value is the value you compare to
            strTextSearch = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c.Value, refRng, 1, False)

            'If the values match
            If c.Value <> vbNullString And strTextSearch = c.Value Then
                Call CompareDataType(count, c)
            Else
                MsgBox "Error First Loop: " + c
                Call CompareDataType(count, c)
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub


Sub CompareDataType(count, c)
    Dim strTextSearchDT        As String
    Dim strTextMainDT         As String
    Dim strTextDT              As String
    Dim cd                As Excel.Range

    On Error Resume Next

    '// Change range to data you want to compare
    For Each cd In Tabelle1.Range(Cells(count + 2, 6), Cells(271, 6))
        With cd
            'Set the range from where you take the data
            strTextSearchDT = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cd.Value, Tabelle2.Range("B2:B2978"), 1, False)

            'If the values match
            If cd.Value <> vbNullString And strTextSearchDT = cd.Value Then
                'MsgBox "Success i guess: " + cd
                Exit For
            Else
                MsgBox "Group Data Type Wrong: " + c + " " + cd
                Exit For          
            End If     
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Sry for the ugly formatting, I deleted all the debug.Print so it looks kinda weird.
I hope you can help me or give me a hint how I can make this dynamic, I tried to do it with cells and without, but as soon as i set it with .row.count it wouldn't work anymore.

EDIT1: If I get rid of `On Error Resume Next` I get error 400
Here what the debug looks like with defined A:A values

```
count 1 
count 2 
count 3 
count 4 
c.Value: CellBalAhSumNvm
count 5 
c.Value: BalCurrAvgPerCellNvm
count 6 
c.Value: CellBalAhSumAvgNvm
```

Here what it looks like with the dynamic one:

```
count 1 
count 2 
count 3 
count 4 
count 5
```

It just coninues on with the A column and doesn't even consider going to the 2nd function, seems like c.value isn't getting the right value or something like that.

Regards,
Mathias

Comment: To be honest I can't really see why `Set refRng = Tabelle2.Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))` isn't working, but I would write is as `Set refRng = Tabelle2.Range("A1:A"& Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: Never use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling. This line just hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. Remove that line completely and see if you get any errors. If so tell which and where. You cannot debug/fix a code if you use `On Error Resume Next` like you did.

Comment: I added some debug values to the OP, seems like the dynamic function doesn't give me correct values for the VLookup.

Comment: Is it only Error 400 without a message text? In which line does the error occur when debug the code going through it step-by-step (with F8). During debug you can also check the values of your variables in each state by selecting the variable and press Shift+F9.

Comment: Why do you start your dynamic range with `A1` but your static range with `A2`?

Comment: Also why do you have a `With cd` statement? It looks like you fully qualify everything anyways - looks like you could just remove that.

Comment: The A1 was just a mistake, the correct one is A2. You are right the With cd statement is not needed, I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:

To get the range variable is used this:

```
 Dim Lastrow              As Integer


         Lastrow = Tabelle2.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
         Set refRng = Tabelle2.Range("A2:A" & Lastrow)
```

For some reason with this it actually moves to the 2nd function as it finds values in c.value which doesn't work with the Cells parameter.